# Docker compose, two services using same image: first fails with "no such image", second runs normally

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab-ci, docker-swarm

**TL;DR**: I have two almost identical services in my compose file except for the name of the service and the published ports. When deploying with `docker stack deploy...`, why does the first service fail with a no such image error, while the second service using the same image runs perfectly fine?

**Full**: I have a docker-compose file with two Apache Tomcat services pulling the same image from my private git repository. The only difference between the two services in my `docker-compose.yml` is the name of the service (`*_dev` vs. `*_prod`) and the published ports. I deploy this docker-compose file on my swarm using the Gitlab CI with the `gitlab-ci.yml`. For the deployment of my docker-compose in this `gitlab-ci.yml` I use two commands:

```
...
   script:
     - docker pull $REGISTRY:$TAG
     - docker stack deploy -c docker-commpose.yml webapp1 --with registry-auth
...
```

(I use a `docker pull [image]` command to have the image on the right node, since my `--with-registry-auth` is not working properly, but this is not my problem currently).

Now the strange thing is that for the first service, I obtain a `No such image:` error and the service is stopped, while for the second service everything seems to run perfectly fine. Both services are on the same worker node. This is what I get if I `docker ps`:

```
:~$ docker service ps webapp1_tomcat_dev
ID          NAME                       IMAGE          NODE           DESIRED STATE       CURRENT STATE             ERROR                              PORTS
xxx1        webapp1_tomcat_dev.1       url/repo:tag   worker1 node   Shutdown            Rejected 10 minutes ago   "No such image: url/repo:tag@xxx…"
xxx2         \_ webapp1_tomcat_dev.1   url/repo:tag   worker1 node   Shutdown            Rejected 10 minutes ago   "No such image: url/repo:tag@xxx…"
:~$ docker service ps webapp1_tomcat_prod
ID          NAME                    IMAGE          NODE           DESIRED STATE       CURRENT STATE            ERROR               PORTS
xxx3        webapp1_tomcat_prod.1   url/repo:tag   worker1 node   Running             Running 13 minutes ago
```

I have used the `--no-trunc` obtain to see that the `IMAGE` used by `*_prod` and `*_dev` is identical.

The `restart_policy` in my docker-compose explains why the first service fails three minutes after the second service started. Here is my docker-compose:

```
version: '3.2'

services:
  tomcat_dev:
    image: url/repo:tag
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        delay: 60s
        window: 120s
        max_attempts: 1
    ports:
      - "8282:8080"

  tomcat_prod:
    image: url/repo:tag
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        delay: 60s
        window: 120s
        max_attempts: 1
    ports:
      - "8283:8080"
```

Why does the first service fail with a no such image error? Is it for example just not possible to have two services, that use the same image, work on the same worker node?

(I cannot simply scale-up one service, since I need to upload files to the webapp which are different for production and development - e.g. `dev` vs `prod` licenses - and hence I need two distinct services)

EDIT: Second service works because it is created first:

```
$ docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml webapp1 --with-registry-auth
Creating service webapp1_tomcat_prod
Creating service webapp1_tomcat_dev
```

Comment: What happens if you try to run a new container outside of docker-compose? Are you able to just create 3 or 4 instances with random names? Provided you mapped the ports correctly and don't use identical names in theory you should be able spawn instances until you run out of memory. Also, when you run docker pull from your script, do you run into the same error? I seems like *_dev does not exist as an image?

Comment: @Ludo21South I have had a `docker exited (137)` code (=OOM) before for one instance when I ran only the first service with a scale=2 on this particular worker, could that be related? How would I check if the first service stopped because of OOM? And should I then check the memory available at the `worker1 node`?

My docker pull command states nothing special besides a `image is up to date for url/repo:tag` message. And both services use this same image so what do you mean exactly with the *_dev does not exist as an image?

Thanks for your reply, it is much appreciated!

Comment: Could it be that the docker pull is not yet finished when the first container is created? Docker stack, in contrast to docker compose, does NOT facilitate building images. What happens when you for example make tomcat_dev depending on the prod? Note: My docker knowledge is pretty basic (and stack virtually non-existant) so I'm just going whatever I think is a way to debug. Also; forget about my docker pull command, I confused name and image name again. The OOM error should not have anything to do with it unless the image can't be build, in which case the PROD should fail as well.

Comment: Nah, the `docker pull` command is completed first before the `docker stack deploy` command is started (I checked my Gitlab CI jobs). Strange thing is that the second service works perfectly fine using the same image. And with a `docker-compose up -d --build` within my project context on my local machine (using `build: context: .` instead of `image: url/repo:tag` in my compose file) also has no problem deploying the two services.

Comment: In that case I'm all out of ideas. Hope someone else can help you out there.

Comment: Thanks, hope some Docker swarm legend reads this as well! PS: Just to clarify: the image `url/repo:tag` simply is my local project context (same Dockerfile) build and pushed with the `docker` commands in the build stage in my `gitlab-ci.yml` - hence deployment locally with `docker-compose up -d --build` is using the same image as with the docker stack deploy

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround by separating my services over two different docker compose files (`docker-compose-prod.yml` and `docker-compose-dev.yml`) and perform the `docker stack deploy` command in my `gitlab-ci.yml` twice:

```
...
   script:
     - docker pull $REGISTRY:$TAG
     - docker stack deploy -c docker-commpose-prod.yml webapp1 --with registry-auth
     - docker pull $REGISTRY:$TAG
     - docker stack deploy -c docker-commpose-dev.yml webapp1 --with registry-auth

...
```

My gut says my `restart_policy` in my docker-compose was too strict as well (had a `max_attempts: 1`) and may be due to this the image couldn't be used in time / within one restart (as suggested by @Ludo21South). Hence I allowed more attempts, but since I already separated the services over two files (which worked already) I have not checked if this hypothesis is true.